# reducing the duplicate records returned in a mysql query when a JOIN returns multiple results?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with my query and one of the joins, the initial query works fine but when i try and join in the links table which has 4 matching links for each article the query returns 4 records for each article thus for displaying each article 4 times on my website?

so my tables are:

```
tbl_news_articles => **newsID**, newsTitle, newsBody, newsDate
tbl_images => **imageID**, filename
tbl_news_images => **imageID**, **newsID**
tbl_links => **linkID**, linkTitle, linkURL
tbl_news_links => **newsID**, **linkID**
```

and my query i am using is

```
SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.date, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename, l.linkID, l.linkTitle, l.linkURL 
FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_news_links AS nlink ON nlink.newsID = n.newsID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_links AS l ON l.linkID = nlink.linkID
```

which returns something like the following

```
newsID, newsTite, newsDesc, newsDate, imageID, filename, linkID, linkTitle, linkURL
65,Article 1 Title,Article 1 description,2016-05-21,1,group.jpg,1,link1 title,linkURL
65,Article 1 Title,Article 1 description,2016-05-21,1,group.jpg,2,link2 title,linkURL
65,Article 1 Title,Article 1 description,2016-05-21,1,group.jpg,3,link3 title,linkURL
65,Article 1 Title,Article 1 description,2016-05-21,1,group.jpg,4,link4 title,linkURL
```

so each article is returned 4 times one for each link.

what is the correct way to resolve this? should i just run a separate query within my php code to get the links separately?

Appreciate your help

my php code is

```
<?php
//call the database to retreive the records
$sql = "SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.date, ni.imageID,      i.imageID, i.filename, l.linkID, l.linkTitle, l.linkURL FROM     tbl_news_articles AS n 
LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_news_links AS nlink ON nlink.newsID = n.newsID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_links AS l ON l.linkID = nlink.linkID 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $row['newsID'];
        $link = "article.php?id=".$id;
        $type = $row['type'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $urltitle = strtolower($title);
        $urltitle = str_replace(" ","-",$urltitle);
        $body = $row['body'];
        #$bodytext = (strlen($body) > 130) ? substr($body,0,130).'...' : $bodytext;
        $pos= strpos($body, ' ', 140);
        $bodytext = substr($body,0,$pos); 
        $bodytext .= "... <a href='$link' title='$title'>read more</a>";
        $date = $row['date'];
        $formated_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date));
        $imgID = $row['imageID'];
        $filename = $row['filename'];
        if($filename != "")
        {
             $imgLink = "images/news-articles/".$id."/".$filename;
        }
        else
        {
             $imgLink = "images/news-item-placeholder.jpg";
        }
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
        {
            echo "<div class='news-spotlight'>";
        }
        elseif($i >=2 && $i <=3)
        {
            if($i == "2")
            {
                $class = "first";
            }
            else
            {
                $class = "";
            }
            echo "<div class='news-highlight $class'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='news-item'>";
        }?>
        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $link?>"><img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo $imgLink?>" alt="<?php echo $title?>" title="<?php echo $title?>"></a>
        <div class='data'>

        <h3><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span itemprop="name"><?php echo $title?></span></a></h3>
        <div class="article-date"><?php echo $formated_date?></div>
        <span itemprop="startDate" content="<?php echo $date?>"></span>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">          
        <span itemprop="address" content="England"></span>
        <span itemprop="name" content="MayoShinDo Association"></span>
        </div>
        <p itemprop="description"><?php echo $bodytext?></p>

    <?php if($i == 1)
    {?>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 4</a></li>
        </ul><?php
    }?>
    </div><?php
    echo "</div>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "0 Results";   
}?>
```

i have not set up the links in the php code yet as you can see from the code above, just want to get the query correct first

i have read you can possibly use GROUP_CONCAT? i tried the following

```
SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.date, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename, l.linkID, l.linkTitle, l.linkURL
GROUP_CONCAT(("|", l.linkID,l.linkTitle,l.linkURL)) as "fieldvalue"
FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_news_links AS nlink ON nlink.newsID = n.newsID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_links AS l ON l.linkID = nlink.linkID
```

but that is saying i have an error in my sql syntax? any ideas

thank you!

Comment: Do you need to join against `tbl_links`?  You don't appear to be using any of the fields from it in your php.

Comment: Do you need a specific link or any duplicate would work? If any duplicate, try to just GROUP BY newsID. Otherwise, you can edit your question with this new knowledge.